# How to get a list of the pictures in my Photo library on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, image, sdk, photo

Is there an API which can give me access to the pictures in my Photo application on iPhone?

Comment: An the reference to it is...?

Comment: Please see my answer for your question.

Comment: Seriously? What's wrong with the search feature that Apple provides? Searching for "photo library" reveals 119 results with the top one being "Picking an item from the Photo Library"

Comment: Sample close to the topic at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoPicker/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [Assets Library framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html) you can refer for getting pictures from photos application of iOS device.

If you want to learn from here [how to use](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/07/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/) Assets Library for picking up multiple pictures. Though it may be off to your requirement but it is nice place to learn how AssetsLibrary Works. There are page links given at the end of tutorial above **`You May Like`**.